String data with " as exterior quote character and \" as interior quote character causing error in GCP BQ Load
I have CSV data that looks like
id, xml
1, "{\"field1\": 1234, \"field2\": \"some string with a comma,\"}"
2, "{\"field1\": 5678, \"field3\": \"some string without a comma\"}"

and it is failing to be read from an external table with CSVOptions set as:
format="CSV"
allow_quoted_newlines=true
quote='\"'
skip_leading_rows=1

with error:
Data between close quote character (") and field separator.; 
line_number: 2 byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 40 column_index: 1 column_name: "xml" column_type: STRING value: "{\\" File: gs://my-bucket.myfile.csv

I have tried various things with the quote value in the CSVOptions: '"', '\"', and even '\\"' which fails because it is not a single character.  Am I just totally dead in the water without formatting the CSV before trying to read it into BQ?
